# Visual Studio 2010 see flow of program (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

can I see flow of program in graph or something like that in VS2010?
if not - what the most efficient way to analyze code?(to understand it !)

Comment: the debugger in vs (in c++) is helpless.

Comment: Do have any other program from which you know this feature? Because AFAIK there is no IDE with such a function...

Comment: I don't if there is something like that , that's why I am asking.If there isn't what is the best way to analyze the code?

Comment: "helpless" seems a rather curious thing to say about the VS debugger, which I've always found to be quite powerful. The most efficient way to understand code is to read through it yourself. Stepping through the code with a debugger and inspecting values as you go will help. There may be profiling tools that can help you more, but you may have to start spending money at that point.

Comment: Why debugger is useless?

Comment: Rook - you right tnx.btw, which tools?

Comment: Denis - I can't see the stack and other vars.I don't understand how to work with it well.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has always had tools to let you see which functions call which, in a tree-like display. I haven't used that in like 15 years and I'm not going to download VS 2010 over this slow connection to just find out the details of mouse-clicks etc., but do look around. However, keep in mind that the reason I haven't used the capability, is that it's mainly of very limited value.

And in general the tool support for *understanding* code is very limited, because understanding is based on intelligence, which cannot in general be captured by simple rules or stuff that tools can do.

If they could, then programmers would be out of work!

A first step towards understanding code is to gain some impression of what kind of abstraction is most important. For example, if your focus is on control flow while the code is mostly object oriented with focus on state, then you will probably have a very difficult time understanding it – because the control goes apparently arbitrarily all over the place. And correspondingly, if your focus is on state, and the code is mainly procedural, then again it will be hard to understand.

I think the best tools are **paper and pen**.

Draw control flow graphs, draw data flows, create association diagrams, draw class boxes, draw object hierarchies, *whatever that seems relevant*.

And don't hesitate to crumble a piece of paper you've used, into a tight ball, and throwing it into the waste-basket. :-)

It also generally helps to *talk with others* about it (when you have studied it enough to have good insights and questions), and to *try to explain* it. For the latter you don't necessarily need other people to listen to you. You can just sit down and try to write up your thoughts, as if writing a tutorial on the thing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was an easy answer but that is useful

Answer (score 0):

I always use Understand For C++ from http://www.scitools.com/ for big C++ projects. This tool is very good at following code, albeit not at run-time.